# VBox maximize problem on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, window, virtualbox, maximize

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 on VBox v4.0.4. My problem is, I can't maximize the ubuntu window. It normally just stuck at the center of the VBox.

I already tried installing guest additions then restart but no luck. It doesn't worked. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press Host+F key for full screen and press the same combination again. Now resize the window and click on Maximize button.

Comment: There are some window resizing options in the Machine menu. Try them in combinations.